# Android developing for Tablet and Phone

Tags: android

I am developing an application for an Android Phone and Tablet. Now the UI's for both phones will be different. Does it make sense to create two different projects for both devices, or would it make more sense to use a single project and use different layouts ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Single project, different layouts.

Comment: Depends alot on if the components on screen are completely different or just in a different layout. And if there are any other differences than just the visual part. By default, I would say: Choose the right layout accordint to screensize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are number of way to handle Different screen size device in one application

Like

1. Handling by different `Drawable folder` Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558534/do-i-need-14-different-layouts-to-support-all-android-devices)
2. By handling different `Drawable Layout` Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414178/multiple-screen-support-do-we-need-different-layouts-for-each-screen?lq=1)
3. By coding get the size of device and change some UI according it.(Which is hard task)

Which is depends on number of parameters like Graphics of application, size of application etc

Sometimes you have to use both different `Drawable Folder` and different `Dravable Layout` for better application performance

Use according to your use

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use a single project with different layouts, unless the phone and tablet UIs are so different that they are essentially different applications.

Note that you may need even more than two layouts, to support different sizes of phones and tablets, different resolutions, different orientations, etc.  Much better to have all of those in one project than to have lots of projects.

Also note that if you use two projects, you would have to distribute two different apps in Google Play, which customers would probably find confusing.

Comment: You could probably use version targeting to have the right customers see only the version you want them to see, but you still wouldn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make different projects for both devices. You need to make different - 2 layout for different - 2 resolution device.
read below document :-

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

also see below link:-

[Most popular screen sizes/resolutions on Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272384/most-popular-screen-sizes-resolutions-on-android-phones)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for application developes to support various devices. The best reference is [that](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Read this and you will understand that you don' t have to create two different projects.