# android fitting screen

Tags: android, layout, screen

I'm developing an app in Android that has a plenty of views(pages). I have to support all phone different screen sizes and density. So i've created different folder for layout : `layout-small`, `layout-large` and `layout`.
Actually I'm not sure about `layout-large` and `layout-xlarge`. But it's not the case.

Then I've created different folder for images: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. In all drawable folders the images are with different size.
I've checked my app with 480x800 160dpi, 480x800 240dpi and 480x800 120dpi it's all OK.

But at 320x480 160dpi app doesn't fit the screen hight. And though I've put a ScrollView still it's not the right way to scroll each new view.

I'm making this app for Android 2.0 and above, so can't use layout-w320dp(like for Android 3).
I need to fit my app at 320x480 160dpi! But how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using relative screen size, then android will adjust that for you

[How do you make layouts for several Android screen sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360868/how-do-you-make-layouts-for-several-android-screen-sizes)

Comment: I've tried but it does not help. So I made some elements smaller and it helped a little.